# CNN architectures for predicting next frame

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing, autoencoders

I am currently trying to generate image of a body tissue at time t+1, by using image given at time t (or t-1,t-2...). Until now, I experimented on some Incomplete Conv Autoencoders in two main approaches,

- the first one is feeding 3 images that represent different aspect of the same tissue at time t and predicting 3 outputs corresponding same aspects a.k.a. 3 channel input 3 channel output.
- the second one is feeding 3 images that represent different aspect of the same tissue at time t and predicting 1 output for a specific aspect. And doing this for all aspects a.k.a. 3 channel input 1 channel output for each channel.

[image: Example data]

In each approach, MSE is used.

Is there a more suitable architecture or approach to this problem? I also checked the literature about future frame prediction but cannot find anything about the medical implementation. Also looking forward to some paper suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, models are deployed to learn rules from data, and the ultimate question for you (since I am not a medical researcher) is that, **does the kind of data that you are feeding into your network contain sufficient information that hints at the rules (e.g. of how body tissues evolve)**? In other words, if you were to predict the next frame yourself instead of using the model, is it possible?

In my experience, it is very difficult to predict the data at time $t+1$ using only the data at time $t$. For example, it is not a trivial task (even for humans) to predict the $t+1$ th word in a book given only the $t$ th word.

However, this task could be made slightly easier if $t-1, t-2, ... t-100$ th words are also provided. This is the underlying idea of recurrent neural networks, in which the output at a time-step depends on the input of many previous time-steps.

My suggestion is to look through papers of recurrent neural networks and watch for some hybrid models between recurrent neural networks (for learning time dependencies) and convolutional neural network (for image processing).